# How to get the Vertical Scrollbar and Horizontal Scrollbar in WPF (XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF desktop application I've got a ListBox that must show the Vertical Scrollbar and Horizontal Scrollbar.

The two scrollbars could be visible or not, basing on the screen resolution.

In the code I want to know if are both visible or only one, to trigger an autoscroll.

I'm using the VisualTreeHelper class to get the list of children of the dependency object (the ListBox itself) and extract all the ScrollViewers.

Here the method:

```
private List<DependencyObject> FindChildren(DependencyObject o, Type childType)
        {
            List<DependencyObject> foundChildren = new List<DependencyObject>();
            if (o != null)
            {
                int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(o);
                for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
                {
                    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(o, i);
                    if (child.GetType() != childType)
                    {
                        foundChildren.AddRange(FindChildren(child, childType));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foundChildren.Add(child);
                    }
                }
            }
            return foundChildren;
        }
```

When both the ScrollBars are visible on the UI, it always return the Horizontal One, and i cannot get the Vertical one.

[image: Listbox with Two Scrollbars]

Any help and/or suggestion is Appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you should just call `Listbox.ScrollIntoView()`. Leave the visual  tree alone.

Comment: Yep the problem is: ScrollIntoView() is not empty, but need an object item as parameter. I tried this way passing the SelectedItem, but the problem is that the horizontal scrollbar is just OVER the last element, so it's not visible to the user. What I need is to autoscroll down when the selected element is the last one.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot - why is the last item cut off so high? It looks as if your horizontal scrollbar is *huge*. Any odd styling happening there?

Comment: Ok, but I still need a way to get BOTH the scrollviewers. Any ideas?